# How to access HTTPS API from HTTP server using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to integrate an API request with jQuery but I get a "Mixed Content" error because my website is HTTP:// and the API website is HTTPS://. I dont'want to use an SSL certificate on  my site. How I can communicate with the API?

This is the code I use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hello");
    jQuery.post('http://example.net/privacy/test.php',function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
```

and use:

```
$.getJSON('//www.mindicador.cl/api', function(data) { ... });
```

Is this possible? Thanks for the help.

Comment: the api should have a http route as well

Comment: Are you sure about the URLs? You'll only get that warning if *your* site is https:// and the request is made to a http:// URL

Comment: @Rory McCrossan : Thanks for your response.. Actually i created html file on volusion store which is on https and my ajax url is of http. That why i am getting error. I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: @madalin ivascu: I tried using https before the ajax url, but its not working. It gives me mixed content error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bypass this directly.

You could work around the issue by setting up an HTTP domain that server-side just gets the content of the HTTPS site and returns it, thereby bypassing the HTTPS issues since the new domain's JavaScript would be running from an HTTP domain and so could call the HTTP endpoint.

Or you could proxy the call, by setting up (or using some existing) HTTPS endpoint, and having that endpoint call the HTTP endpoint and return the contents it gets from the HTTP endpoint. That way the JavaScript on the HTTPS domain is only ever talking to HTTPS endpoints.